# Gadfly adjust axis

Tags: julia, gadfly, ijulia-notebook

I don't have much experiencie with Gadfly package in Julia language and I wish I know if there is a solution for my problem. This is my first question here.

I need to plot a graphic that values in axis x are [1.0 0.1 0.01 0.001 0.0001 0.00001 0.000001] and I only have results for these parameters for five case tests. I wish I have to plot the graphic in a good visible way to see the results. The poor result is consequence of the fact that the numbers in the interval are very close and I want to adjust the space between them.

[My poor plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLjxC.png)

Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Use a log scale?

Comment: Use log-scale. Take a look at the gadfly tutorial: http://gadflyjl.org/stable/tutorial.html and search for `Scale.x_log10`.

Comment: Thanks for help guys! I didn't pay attention when on this when I looked the tutorial.